# how can i use array list of activities instead of using multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, android-pageradapter

in my project which about viewing multiple activities with swipe i have been used the fragments idea and my code work very well ,, but this morning my manager asked me to convert the array list of fragments to array list of activities 
but really i don't know how i can do this please any help this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    List < Fragment > fragments;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        fragments = new Vector < Fragment > ();

        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentOne.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentTwo.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentThree.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentFour.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentFive.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentSix.class.getName()));

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            int _pos = position % 6;
            return fragments.get(_pos);
        }

        @
        Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 6;
        }

        @
        Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            final String title_section4 = "Section4";
            final String title_section5 = "Section5";
            final String title_section6 = "Section6";
            final String title_section1 = "Section1";
            final String title_section2 = "Section2";
            final String title_section3 = "Section3";

            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return title_section1.toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return title_section2.toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return title_section3.toUpperCase(l);
                case 3:
                    return title_section4.toUpperCase(l);
                case 4:
                    return title_section5.toUpperCase(l);
                case 5:
                    return title_section6.toUpperCase(l);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentOne() {}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentTwo() {}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class FragmentThree extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentThree() {}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.three, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class FragmentFour extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentFour() {}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.four, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class FragmentFive extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentFive() {}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.five, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class FragmentSix extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentSix() {}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.six, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you can't use  Activity with view pagers anyway you have  to use fragments.Its Applicable if you are using view-pager  in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Your project into MainActivity use Fragments no Activities

I think if you want use Swipe view you can't use an Array Activities because Swipe View it's based in ViewPager and need Fragments.

So I think it's impossible does "swipe views" with Activities.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: aha ok ,,thanks ,, mmmmm do you have any idea to this please ?

Comment: can i ask other question please